# laravel storage exists returns false although file exists

Tags: php, laravel, file, storage, exists

I am modifying an uploaded pdf with Fpdi, in laravel.
The pdf is generated perfectly, I can see it in any file explorer. But laravel built in Storage::exists() returns false.
It is a pretty weird error, because php file_exists method can find the file perfectly with the same path, as well as File::exists

I am completely out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated!

The src variable is made by Storage::path()

```
$src = Storage::path("notes/".$this->note->id."-downgraded.pdf");
Storage::disk('public')->exists($src); //this returns false
file_exists($src); //this returns true
File::exists($src) //this returns true
```

Comment: Have you tried with `File::exists($src)`

Comment: @HassaanAli Thanks for the idea, File:exists returns true as well!

Comment: Please correct me, you want to use `Storage::disk` only to handle files?

Comment: can you give some additional information about `$src`? In addition please have a look at the public disc documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk. If you use a disk, this disk usually has a base path configured, therefore `$src` should be relative to this path.

Comment: @Tschitsch Thanks for the finding, I updated the question

Comment: @HassaanAli  yes, I wanted to use Storage::disk ->get() to get the file and then upload it. 

The weird thing is that I could use File:get to get the file but not Storage:disk->get.

Although I use Storage:disk->get for generating preview pdf files, and it works perfectly in that case..

So after all, thanks to you I could manage to make it work by using File instead of Storage, (which gave me a lot of headache recently), but I still dont understand it.

Comment: You can't access the public route using storage disk function. It's used to access private storage inside laravel application. In order to access the public directory File::exists is used to access it. :)

Comment: @HassaanAli Thanks for all the help. But the weirdest thing, that this pdf manipulating function creates 2 pdf, with exactly the same method. And with one of them Storage:disk->get works, and with one of them it doesnt, only the File::get. If Storage disk shall not be used to access public storage, why is it working in one occasion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that your laravel project is using the default laravel filesystem configuration.

If you use `Storage:disk('public')` then the root-directory on this disk is different from `Storage:path()`.
That means that you've actually retrieved `$src` from one disk and checking its existence on a completely different disk.

If you use `Storage` without a disk, then the default-disk will be used. By default, it is `local`, therefore
`$src` is something like this: `/my-project/storage/app/notes/some.pdf`.
(see `./config/filesystem.php` to check your actual disk and default config)

You checked existence like this: `Storage::disk('public')->exists($src)`.
This means that you look for `/my-project/storage/app/notes/some.pdf` on the public-disk.
The root-directory of the public-disk is in general `/my-project/storage/app/public`.

That means that the exists-method is actually checking the existence of
`/my-project/storage/app/public/my-project/storage/app/notes/some.pdf`.
I assume this is not what you expected to happen.

Your exists-check should look like this:

```
# public disk root-directory is configured this: 
# /my-project/storage/app/public

# file is actually here: 
# /my-project/storage/app/public/notes/some.pdf

$src = "notes/some.pdf"
Storage::disk('public')->exists($src);
```

Using `Storage` does not require you to know the absolute paths of files at all. Used properly you don't even need to care about the location of the files at all.

I highly recommend reading the manual here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work using File instead of Storage thanks to a comment made by Hassaan Ali